# In C++ what would be the best efficient way of loading a file with key / value between quotes, trimming blanks

Tags: c++

What would be the best efficient way to load a file into a `std::map` that has this format as an example:

```
6356 "text description"
f57hn    "Read disk 3.5" size"
fhjhb   "Prefix with "solved" text"
```

Notice the variable number of blanks between the key and the value.

The value should be loaded in the `map` without the initial and final quotes, but with the quotes in the middle intact.

Comment: What does "best" mean to you? Can you define it using some objective, fact-based criteria? Otherwise what's "best" would be a matter of opinion, and opinion-based questions are not appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Best it means in performance evaluation in this case

Comment: Well, if that's the case, I would memory-map the file, then use pointers to manually parse and extract the data. The End.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach:

1. Read the file one line at a time with [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
2. Put the line into a [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)
3. Extract the key from the stream using `operator>>`
4. Extract the remainder from the stream after using [std::ws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) to absorb the whitespace
5. Remove the leading and trailing quote marks

A possible approach summarizing steps 2-5:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string someLine = "f57hn    \"Read disk 3.5\" size\"";
    std::istringstream someStream(someLine);

    std::string key;
    someStream >> key;
    std::cout << "key = " << key << '\n';

    std::string remainder;
    getline(someStream >> std::ws, remainder);
    std::cout << "remainder = " << remainder << '\n';

    if(remainder.size() > 1 && remainder.front() == '"' && remainder.back() == '"')
    {
        remainder = remainder.substr(1, remainder.size() - 2);
    }
    std::cout << "stripped remainder = " << remainder << '\n';
}
```

Sample output:

```
key = f57hn
remainder = "Read disk 3.5" size"
stripped remainder = Read disk 3.5" size
```

Comment: Small nitpick - use `std::istringstream` instead of `std::stringstream`, since `someStream` is only read from and never written to.